# Get the key from a sub-dictionary and a value from a list of key-val pairs within it

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, subdirectory

I have a dictionary called metadata. It has a length of 2 keys, 'status' and 'data'. I am only interested in the key 'data' and what lies within it. The subdictionary 'data' has 1,136 keys.

```
{'status': 'success',
 'data': {'async_tasks_count': [{'type': 'gauge',
    'help': 'Total number of async tasks spawned using spawn',
    'unit': ''}],
  'async_tasks_time_histogram': [{'type': 'histogram',
    'help': 'Time taken by async tasks',
    'unit': ''}],
  'attestation_production_cache_interaction_seconds': [{'type': 'histogram',
    'help': 'Time spent interacting with the attester cache',
    'unit': ''}],
  'attestation_production_cache_prime_seconds': [{'type': 'histogram',
    'help': 'Time spent loading a new state from the disk due to a cache miss',
    'unit': ''}]}
```

Within 'data' I need the Key and the Value of the 1st position (i.e. second elelment). For example the first Key within 'data' would be 'async_tasks_count' and the Value I need is 'Total number of async tasks spawned using spawn', the second Value.

It would be ideal to have them returned like:

('async_tasks_count' : 'Total number of async tasks spawned using spawn',
'async_tasks_time_histogram' : 'Time taken by async tasks',
'attestation_production_cache_interaction_seconds': 'Time spent interacting with the attester cache',
'attestation_production_cache_prime_seconds': 'Time spent loading a new state from the disk due to a cache miss')

I'm using Python3

Comment: So the end result should be something like this? `{ 'async_tasks_count': metadata['data']['async_tasks_count'][0]['help'], 'async_tasks_time_histogram': metadata['data']['async_tasks_time_histogram'][0]['help'], 'attestation_production_cache_interaction_seconds': metadata['data']['attestation_production_cache_interaction_seconds'][0]['help'], 'attestation_production_cache_prime_seconds': metadata['data']['attestation_production_cache_prime_seconds'][0]['help'] }`

Comment: No, like this ('async_tasks_count' : 'Total number of async tasks spawned using spawn', 'async_tasks_time_histogram' : 'Time taken by async tasks') @kmoser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through `data` dictionary and then extract `help` property from each item.

The `item` is the dictionary with the `data` property.

```
result = {}
for key, value in metadata['data'].items():
    result[ key ] = value[0].get('help')
    
print(result) # for viewing the result
```

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Comment: There was a closing dict bracket missing in your code

Comment: Perfection sir!